# Recognize start of piano music in an MP3 file which starts with a spoken introduction, and remove spoken part, using Python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, piano

I have a number of .mp3 files which all start with a short voice introduction followed by piano music. I would like to remove the voice part and just be left with the piano part, preferably using a Python script. The voice part is of variable length, ie I cannot use ffmpeg to remove a fixed number of seconds from the start of each file.
Is there a way of detecting the start of the piano part and then know how many seconds to remove using ffmpeg or even using Python itself?.
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. Post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so as to get help

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-trivial problem if you want a good outcome.

Quick and dirty solutions would involve inferred parameters like:

- "there's usually 15 seconds of no or low-db audio between the speaker and the piano"
- "there's usually not 15 seconds of no or low-db audio in the middle of the piano piece"

and then use those parameters to try to get something "good enough" using audio analysis libraries.

I suspect you'll be disappointed with that approach given that I can think of many piano pieces with long pauses and this reads like a classic ML problem.

The best solution here is to use ML with a classification model and a large data set. Here's [a walk-through that might help you get started](https://www.iotforall.com/tensorflow-sound-classification-machine-learning-applications/). However, this isn't going to be a few minutes of coding. This is a typical ML task that will involve collecting and tagging lots of data (or having access to pre-tagged data), building a ML pipeline, training a neural net, and so forth.

Here's [another link that may be helpful](https://towardsdatascience.com/audio-classification-with-pre-trained-vgg-19-keras-bca55c2a0efe). He's using a pretrained model to reduce the amount of data required to get started, but you're still going to put in quite a bit of work to get this going.

Comment: Thank you Kerasbaz, you have given me at least two options. Since the spoken part is at the front of the file, one solution would be to be able to try and detect the first non-sound gap in the file and the length of time to get there. The other solution would rely on your second link, but I need time to evaluate it. But I would welcome any assistance with the first solution.